# Disable touchscreen gestures Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen, gestures

I need to disable all the touchscreen gestures, like the left-border slide that opens activities and the bottom-border slide that opens the onscreen keyboard, in order to have only the single tap for a fullscreen application that runs on startup. Any suggestions?